# Why tabular doesn't work with ModernCV

Tags: tables, moderncv

When I try to insert a tabular in my CV using modernCV document like this

```
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
 \hline aa & bb & cc \\
 \hline dd & ee & ff \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}
```

I don't get any border. It appears that it's not possible to make a tabular in a moderncv. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order for rules in `tabular` to appear, each document class has to define a positive value for `\arrayrulewidth` and `moderncv` either doesn't assign a value or it sets it to `0pt`; something similar happens to `\tabcolsep`; simply assign the standard values for those lengths:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\firstname{A}
\familyname{B}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4pt}
\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
 \hline aa & bb & cc \\
 \hline dd & ee & ff \\
 \hline
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In fact, there was an attempt to set these lengths (and some others) in `moderncv.cls`, but the author decided they were not required; one can see

```
% not required
%\setlength\arraycolsep{5\p@}
%\setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
%\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}
%\setlength\doublerulesep{2\p@}
%\setlength\tabbingsep{\labelsep}
```

in `moderncv.cls`.

As a personal suggestion, consider removing vertical rules from your tables and using the `booktabs` package.